# Number from MySQL database to be formated with comma

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm currently running a php website that pulls data from a mysql database. At the moment i have a column, we can call this "views" the numbers that are in this column are just digits and not recognised as numbers and therefore have no commas to separate the numbers. So the code onsite will look something like this:

```
<div><b>Views: </b><?=$views?></div>
```

I have been able to take a column that is showing seconds to be formated in a minuite/seconds format:

```
<div><b>Length: </b><?=gmdate("i:s", $length)?></div>
```

But I am unable to find out how I can format the numbers to include commas, at the moment a number will pull as "1000000" but I would like to format it so that the user will see "1,000,000".

Thanks in advance.

p.s If you do know how to do this and know of any documentation could you link me to that also.

**Solved** by "Paulo Lima"

Code would look like:

**Views:**

Comment: You mean like the [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) or [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) functions?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php

```
number_format( $views, 0 , "." , "," );
```

No decimal places. Dot for decimal point, comma for thousands separator.